# LWJGL 3 : StackGet() usage

Tags: java, lwjgl

I've always wondered if I'm using stackPush() and stackGet() correctly.
Currently, if I have to use stack, I will first make something like:

```
try (var stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
...
}
```

Then, if i'm calling a method within the try block, I will use stackGet() to avoid passing the stack in the parameters of the method:

```
try (var stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
foo();
}
...
void foo() {
var stack = stackGet();
...
}
```

I don't find any real explanation about stackGet() on the javadoc, so am I correctly using this function? Does someone can explain me the difference between stackPush() and stackGet() if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

LWJGL 3's `MemoryStack` holds a fixed amount of off-heap (native) memory per thread as a `ThreadLocal` variable. The static method `MemoryStack.stackPush()` will do a `ThreadLocal` lookup of the per-thread instance of `MemoryStack` via `MemoryStack.stackGet()` followed by an instance method call to `MemoryStack.push()`. And as a result of `stackPush()` you will simply be given the already looked-up thread-local instance of `MemoryStack` for your calling thread.

For optimal performance, you should therefore "drag" this `MemoryStack` instance into other methods and avoid calling `MemoryStack.stackGet()`.

However, it might be possible, that the JVM (within its inline boundary) will optimize multiple calls to `MemoryStack.stackGet()` (or rather the thread-local lookup therein) to a single lookup at the beginning, since no other thread could have altered the calling thread's thread-local value.